# Filtering on foreign key null doesn't work in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is a brief sample of the model setup and the query I am trying. This didn't give me any errors in Django 1.6, but in 1.7 it gives me an exception. The "implicit" foreign key is not available on the Interface queryset, it seems. I tried both select_related('gwportprefix') and prefetch_related('gwportprefix') with no luck.

```
class Interface(models.Model):
    # Several fields here that are not related.
    pass

class GwPortPrefix(models.Model):
    interface = models.ForeignKey('Interface', db_column='interfaceid')

for gwport in Interface.objects.filter(gwportprefix__isnull=False):
    gwport_matches.add(gwport)
```

This gives the following FieldError:

Cannot resolve keyword 'gwportprefix' into field. Choices are (Everything directly on Interface. No implicit foreignkeys)

Answer (score 1):

in django 1.7 many changes occurred in the QuerySet / Manager implementation. Have you tried ?

```
Interface.objects.filter(gwportprefix_set__isnull=False)
```

Comment: Gives me the same exception with keyword 'gwportprefix_set' instead.